# Hard drive swap/upgrade - a few questions

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd

I am thinking of upgrading my HDD (hopefully to SSD) in my Asus K53S laptop.

If I just pull out my old HDD and plug in a new one will my computer boot up as normal and allow me to log on? If not, would I just have to copy all the content from the old hard drive to the new one and if so just Select all, Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V. Just not sure how I would go about it.

Running Windows 7 Home Premium 64 Bit

Any help would be appreciated...Thanks

Comment: There are dozens of software packages that will let you clone your current HDD to another HDD or SSD.  Copying and pasting your files will not acomplish what you want to do.

Comment: If this is the OS drive you will need to reinstall your OS or clone it from the old drive to the new one. Most HDD manufacturers offer free cloning software with their drives, so have a look at their web site.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your best option is just to clone the content of your old HDD to the new one.

There are free tools like [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to perform this task. It is advised to run it from a live media (CD or USB), in the end of the process the whole HDD would be cloned, and its contents would be exactly as the old one.